# Strange messages from gems after switching to Xcode 6 and Yosemite

Tags: rubygems, xcode6, osx-yosemite

I recently switched to Xcode 6 and Yosemite.  Now, when I run certain gems I get the following messages. I've seen other questions on here with the same error message, but none of them seem to match this.

Is this due to a known change in the dev environment? 
Do I need to reinstall all my gems?

```
$ mygem start
Ignoring bigdecimal-1.2.5 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bigdecimal-1.2.5
Ignoring debase-0.0.9 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine debase-0.0.9
Ignoring ffi-1.9.3 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi-1.9.3
Ignoring redcarpet-3.1.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine redcarpet-3.1.1
Ignoring xcodeproj-0.17.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine xcodeproj-0.17.0
Ignoring bigdecimal-1.2.5 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bigdecimal-1.2.5
Ignoring debase-0.0.9 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine debase-0.0.9
Ignoring ffi-1.9.3 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi-1.9.3
Ignoring redcarpet-3.1.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine redcarpet-3.1.1
Ignoring xcodeproj-0.17.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine xcodeproj-0.17.0
```

Comment: if you run `gem list` what do you get? I would suggest re-installing using `bundler` or whatever you are using. If that doesn't work then I would recommend uninstalling then installing, should work.

Comment: `gem list` gives me that same list of messages followed by a list of local gems.

Comment: What to you mean by "whatever you are using"?  I do have bundler installed, but uninstalling and reinstalling that did not have an effect on this problem.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but it sounds like they need to be rebuilt and as far as I can tell you will need to run `gem uninstall bundler` then `gem install bundler` and then for each gem that is being ignored running `gem install %gem_name%` an example would be `gem install bigdecimal`.

Comment: Another thing you could try is `gem pristine --all` I have heard of this working for some

Comment: `gem install %gemnane%` and then `gem pristine %gemnane%` for each gem in the list fixed the issue.  Please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for each gem that is being ignored you will have to run:

```
gem install %gemname%
```

and then

```
gem pristine %gemname%
```